# Reading from serial port on Linux and OSX

Tags: c, macos, android-ndk, serial-port

I am writing simple CLI application for reading data from serial port. I have USB to serial converter with <del>CP2102</del> and every few seconds, I am receiving 200 B long string.

**Edit:** I made a mistake. It is not a *CP2102*, but *Profilic PL2303*. I also found strange behavior when I use `stty` -- I cannot change baud rate and it's randomly changing:

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB5 57600 # Set baudrate
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB5 # Read configuration
speed 1200 baud;
.....
$$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB5 # Read configuration
speed 9600 baud;
.....
```

**End-of-edit**

When I compile my application under Mac OS X, it works without any problem. But when I compile this code for Linux (cheap Android tablet with ARM CPU, I use Android NDK for compilation) I receive some data, then garbage:

```
~|?>?lq?43??d??2~??O?$?$??c??Hello World, good data.
???5??l??!???????x?????????????fx???~????????????x??????`???????~???f?x???~????`f??f???~?????x??????#ף???????x?????????????fx???~????????????x??????`???????~???f?x???~????`f??f???~??3?
```

It looks like I set wrong baud rate, but I am 100% sure the baud rate is 57600 bauds.

Is the problem in my code (differences in POSIX, Unix, Linux, etc.) or should I look for problems in hardware (CP2102, etc)?

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>     // string function definitions
#include <errno.h>      // Error number definitions
#include <unistd.h>     // UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h>      // File control definitions
#include <termios.h>    // POSIX terminal control definitions

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("Opening device... ");
  int USB = open("/dev/ttyUSB5", O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
  printf("opened.\n");

  struct termios tty;
  struct termios tty_old;
  memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);

  /* Error Handling */
  if (tcgetattr(USB, &tty) != 0) {
    printf("Error %d from tcgetattr: %s!\n", errno, strerror(errno));
  }

  /* Save old tty parameters */
  tty_old = tty;

  /* Set Baud Rate */
  cfsetospeed (&tty, (speed_t)B57600);
  cfsetispeed (&tty, (speed_t)B57600);

  /* Setting other Port Stuff */
  tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;        // Make 8n1
  tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
  tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
  tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;

  tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;       // no flow control
  tty.c_cc[VMIN]  =   1;
  tty.c_cc[VTIME] =   5;
  tty.c_cflag     |=  CREAD | CLOCAL; // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines

  /* Make raw */
  cfmakeraw(&tty);

  /* Flush Port, then applies attributes */
  tcflush(USB, TCIFLUSH);
  if ( tcsetattr ( USB, TCSANOW, &tty ) != 0) {
    printf("Error %d from tcgetattr: %s!\n", errno, strerror(errno));
  }

  int n = 0;
  char buf [256];

  printf("Starting to read data...\n");
  do {
    n = read( USB, &buf, sizeof buf);

    if (n > 0) {
      printf("%s", buf);
      memset(&buf, '\0', sizeof buf);
    }

    usleep(100000);  /* sleep for 100 milliSeconds */
  } while(1);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to reset port parameters to your values without taking into account original paramaters? I.e. without tcgetattr?

Comment: First time round, buf is not intialialized to nulls, so the printf(%s..) will blow up.  When you have n, just set the n'th char to '\0', no need for avoidable memset.

Comment: Also, why are you using non-blocking and a sleep() loop?

Comment: I was playing with blocking, non-blocking modes, I added `usleep` and `memset`. This code is just last version of what I tried.